# R, ggplot2 size/dim of elements/dots/lines

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am Using ggplot2 for plotting this image:

The thing is: On the X-Axes are ranges. What I would like to do: I would like to make each dot/line/whatever as big as the ranges (written on the X-Axes) are.

Is that possible? My code looks like:

```
ggplot(data, aes(as.character(paste(data$V3,data$V4,sep="-")), means, color = factor(numSamp),group = 1))+
  geom_point()+
  stat_smooth(method = "lm")
```

[image]

Cheers,

Mario

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. I'm not sure I understand, or that what you are plotting even makes sense. Perhaps if you made a [reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) that demonstrates your question / problem, people would find it easier to answer.

Comment: Ditto to what Andre said.  But to wager a guess: does using `geom_point(aes(size=V3))` or whatever you want as the size dimension work?

Comment: @Justin, geom_point is what I was looking for! Thanks. BTW: Sorry for my unclear question.